# Weird Nebensatz with "zu sein"

Tags: sentence-structure

> Wir können uns nicht erlauben, Geschäfte zu machen mit, **was immer man Ihnen vorwirft zu sein**.

I understand the meaning but I can't figure out the grammar behind this sentence. Why is there "zu sein"? I feel it is redundant. Can you guys please give me examples of sentences like this or explain to me the grammar behind it?

Comment: This reads like a word-to-word mistranslation from English. German prepositions cannot simply take a relative clause as their complement: we cannot write "...mit was er ist", we **must** write "mit dem, was er ist".

Comment: @KilianFoth I do agree the construct is uncommon, but do not agree it's wrong. "Sei, was immer du sein willst"  works perfectly in German.

Comment: @tofro That's not a preposition. Relative clauses used as pseudo-nominals, as in "Tu, was du willst" are common. But relative clauses as complements of prepositions don't exist except as mistranslations. (Of course, today's mistranslation may be tomorrow's construction...)

Comment: Kilian Foth hat Recht. Man macht Geschäfte mit **jemanden**, aber nicht mit **etwas**. Vermutlich ist so etwas gemeint wie "Wir können uns nicht erlauben, Geschäfte zu machen, bei dem was man Ihnen vorwirft, zu sein."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple reason why *zu sein* may at first glance be felt as superfluous: *was* lends itself to be misinterpreted as the accusative object of *vorwerfen*.

> Ich weiß nicht, **was** man ihm vorwirft.
> *I don't know what he is being accused of.*

However, *vorwerfen* can also govern an infinitive clause.

> Man wirft ihm vor, **gelogen zu haben**.
> *He is accused of having lied.*

In the original example, *was* is not the accusative object of *vorwerfen*, but the predicative complement of the verb *sein* in the infinitive clause (with the infinitive clause being the object of *vorwerfen*). Compare:

> Man wirft ihm vor, **ein Mörder zu sein**.
> *He is accused of being a murderer.*

We can replace *ein Mörder* by *was*, forming a so-called [echo question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echo_question).

> Wie bitte? Man wirft ihm vor, **was** zu sein?
> *Come again? He is accused of being what?*

In certain clauses the wh-word needs to be fronted, leading to something German grammarians have neatly called *Satzverschränkung* ("sentence interleaving"). The bold parts in the following sentences belong together, but *was* stands at the front of the matrix clause, not within the embedded clause.

> **Was** wirft man ihm vor **zu sein**?
> *What is he accused of being?*

> Ich kann nicht glauben, **was** man ihm vorwirft, **getan zu haben**.
> *I cannot believe what he is accused of having done.*

In linguistics, the convention is to indicate the base position of an fronted element by an indexed variable (in generative grammar, *t* stands for [trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_movement#Traces)), possibly clarifying the sentence structure.

> Ich kann nicht glauben, was<sub>i</sub> man ihm vorwirft, *t*<sub>i</sub> getan zu haben.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thank you I understand it now.

Answer (score 2):

*was immer man ihnen vorwirft, zu sein* is a relative clause (more exactly: a *freier Relativsatz*, because it doesn't relate to a nominative part of the sentence, but rather is one itself) used as a prepositional object (with "mit").

I don't know your native language, but the sentence can be literally translated to English as

> We cannot do business with whatever you are accused to be

(Note, English needs the "to be" as well - because you cannot do business with an accusation, only with a person)

Let's, for example, assume the accusation is "Mord".

*was immer man ihnen vorwirft* == "ein Mord"

*was immer man ihnen vorwirft, zu sein* == "ein Mörder"

Thus, you can't do busines with *murder* - but you could do business with *a murderer*.

Comment: German tends to use the infinitive where English uses the "-ing" form, or stated the other way, English tends to use the "-ing" form where German uses the infinitive. So I would say "accused of being" rather than "accused to be". This seems like a difficult sentence to translate since *vorwerfen* can be interpreted number of ways in English (e.g. 'blame", "reproach"), but only "accuse" seems to be workable here.

Answer (score 1):

That's just the way we accuse someone *of something* in German using *vorwerfen* - we use an infinitive with *zu*.

> Man wirft Ihnen vor, Herrn Müller ein Stinktier genannt zu haben.
> *You are being accused of having called Mr. Müller a skunk.*

> Man wirft Ihnen vor, ein Betrüger zu sein.
> *You are being accused of being a fraud.*

> Was auch immer man Ihnen vorwirft zu sein, wir vertrauen Ihnen.
> *Whatever you are accused of being, we trust you.*

Answer (score -1):

- Without *zu sein*:

  "Was immer man Ihnen vorwirft" is an act that you are said to have committed. (*Whatever you are accused of*)

  > Wir können uns nicht erlauben, Geschäfte zu machen mit, was immer man Ihnen vorwirft.
  > We cannot afford to do business with whatever you are accused of.
- With *zu sein*:

  "Was immer man Ihnen vorwirft zu sein" is the type of person that you are accused to be. (*Whatever you are accused to be*)

  > Wir können uns nicht erlauben, Geschäfte zu machen mit, was immer man Ihnen vorwirft **zu sein.**
  > We cannot afford to do business with whatever you are accused **to be.**

Comment: Your examples without "zu sein" don't make a lot of sense. You can't do business with an accusation, even if you want to.