# Kann man ein fernes Objekt durch Infinitvkonstruktion mit zu beherrschen?

Tags: english-to-german, grammaticality

Beim Übersetzen aus dem Altgriechischen ist mir wieder eine syntaktische Struktur aufgestoßen, die auf English leicht parallel nachzubilden ist, die mir aber auf Deutsch immer Probleme bereitet:

Das Griechische/Englische lautet:

- ... πράξαντας ταῦθ' ἁ πάντες γλίσχονται λέγειν, ...  (Dem.6.11)
- ... (that your ancestors) have done things, which everyone strives to put to words.

Es ist ein Teil von einer längeren Periode. Daher ist ´that your ancestors´ schon ein Objektsatz.

Das Problem, woran ich immer scheitere, wenn ich versuche, eine schöne deutsche Übersetzung von ähnlichen syntaktischen Konstruktionen zu finden, liegt darin, dass ich die Nebensätze nie richtig organisieren kann.

Mein bester Versuch:

...(dass eure Vorfahren) Täten vollgebracht haben, die alle immer streben, mit Wörter auszudrücken.

Ich bin nur immer nicht sicher, ob man den Satz auch so konstruieren kann, dass man sich zwar an das Objekt der ersten Objekt-Nebensatz (Täten) durch das Relativpronomen (die ...) anknüpft, aber das Objekt nur ganz am ende mit einem Verbum 'beherrscht' wird, das in einer infinitiven Konstruktion mit ´zu´ steht.

Comment: (Ich kann kein Altgriechisch.) Muss die Übersetzung so wörtlich sein? Beim ersten Teil des Satzes ist die Übersetzung doch auch freier ("T[a]ten vollbracht" statt "Dinge getan"). Gutes Deutsch wäre etwas wie "(dass eure Vorfahren) Taten vollbracht haben, von denen jeder berichten will." Man könnte es auch sehr viel lyrischer ausdrücken, aber mangels Sprachkenntnis kann ich das Original diesbezüglich nicht einschätzen.

Comment: Ansonsten, ja, der "beste Versuch" is vom Satzbau in Ordnung, wenn auch sehr gezwungen. "Täten"  is falsch, der Plural ist "Taten". "Wörter"  müsste korrekt dekliniert werden ("mit Wörtern"), aber man würde hier den alternativen Plural (vgl. [DWDS-Eintrag](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Wort)) verwenden: "mit Worten". Statt "ausdrücken" könnte "beschreiben" besser passen (häufig liest man in Texten aus dem Mittelalter "besingen").

Comment: @Roland Für Antworten gibt es weiter unten extra ein Feld!

Comment: Ein paralleles Beispiel hier: https://german.stackexchange.com/a/67155/35111

Answer (score 2):

> .. (that your ancestors) have done things, which everyone strives to put to words.

würde fast wörtlich übersetzt auf deutsch lauten:

> ... (dass eure Vorfahren) Taten vollbracht haben, die jedermann in Worte zu fassen strebt.

oder, auf etwas niedrigerem Sprachniveau und angelehnt an Rolands Vorschlag:

> ... vollbracht haben, von denen jeder berichten möchte.

Ich habe *immer* weggelassen, das finde ich im Englischen auch nicht.

Comment: Nach einem kurzen Blick in den Gemoll würde ich übersetzen: _die jeder zu berichten trachtet_. Dann spart man sich die Präpositionen. Aber es klingt natürlich altertümelnder.

Comment: *Richtig* altertümlich wäre *die zu berichten jeder trachtet* :-)